# appcelerator orientationchange navbar image hide / show

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, navbar, orientation-changes

I'm building an app with some tabs for the iPhone.
rephrased the question in the appcelerator website [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120038/on-orientationchange-navbar-image-is-streched-when-switching-tabs)

When i change from portrait to landscape i want to hide the navbar.

it works fine if i don't switch to another tab. 
But when i view 1 tab in portrait, 
 switch to another tab, change to landscape view, 
 switch back to the first tab, 
 and then change to back portrait 
the navbar (window.barImage) is all stretched out ( to the size of a landscape navBar )

Also when i remove all my code for hiding the navbar the same problem occurs.

I've tried setting the barImage again on orientationchange but that does not help either.

a site note: I'm using the same image on every tab for the navBar could that be the problem?[image: portrait view of the app showing my problem]

I marked in green the navbar image, the blue part is where the image normally should be.

Also note that the image is the right size for a portrait view of the navbar.

code:

```
var windowWidth = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;

var catWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'',
    barImage: 'images/barImage.png',
    url:'vacancies/categories.js',
    width: windowWidth
});

catWin.orientationModes = [
    Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT,
    Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,
    Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT
];

Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
    if(e.orientation == Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT){
        catWin.hideNavBar();
    } else if(e.orientation == Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT){
        catWin.hideNavBar();
    } else if(e.orientation == Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT){
        catWin.showNavBar();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not the best solution because it still looks a bit odd ( but way better then before, ) this is the best solution until now.
I have found some kind of solution by using the following code:

I've set the barImage in the createWindow code so at least at the beginning it looks OK:

```
var jbWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title: '',
    url:'homePage.js',
    barImage: 'images/jobbroker_bar.png'
});
```

Then on orientationchange I unset the barImage and start using the titleImage:

```
Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e){
   if(e.source.isLandscape()){
      catWin.titleImage = '';
      catWin.barImage = '';
      catWin.hideNavBar();
   else if( e.orientation != Ti.UI.FACE_UP && e.orientation != Ti.UI.FACE_DOWN ) {
      catWin.titleImage = 'images/jobbroker_bar.png';
      catWin.showNavBar();
   }
}
```

Comment: accepted my own awnser since it it the best solution and I'm not gonna search for a better one anymore it's taking to long..

Answer (score 1):

You really need to post more code, for example I have no idea if you are using `Ti.UI.currentWindow.hideNavBar();` or if you are using just the `.hide();` and `.show();`?

From what I can tell you're problem however possibly lies with the the width. Trying setting it to `'100%'` instead of using the `platformWidth`. Once again without **all** the relevant code such as your `orientationchange` event this is best advice I can give. Hope it helps.

**THIRD COMMENT:** possibly

```
Titanium.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
    if(e.source.isLandscape()){
        catWin.hideNavBar();
    } else {
        catWin.barImage = 'images/barImage.png';
        catWin.showNavBar();
    }
});
```

Just somewhere in there or the tab events. I would play around with that idea and see if it gets you any further?

Comment: thanks for your usefull comment! i'm using the hideNavbar() and showNavbar(). I will update my question

Comment: I've tried setting the with to '100%' that didn't help.
Also I don't think the orientationchange is really relevant because if i remove the orientationchange code ( and the hideNavbar / showNavbar ) the Navbar image still got stretched when changing tab and then back to portrait view

Comment: Strange the KS https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/window_navbar.js has trouble with that too. Have you tried adding a reset of the `barImage` to your `orientationchange` event or tab `focus` events? Something like `catWin.barImage = 'images/barImage.png';`? I know it's already set but you can fix almost any table display issues by simply reloading the data in the events so I'm wondering if the `barImage` works the same way...

Comment: I've tried setting the image (again) on orientationchange or tap focus both ending up in the result that the barImage disappears.

Comment: I tried setting the barImage (agian) on orientationchange and tab focus. both ending up in letting the barImage disappear.. Then i removed all the orientationchange / tab focus that affected the bar image and found out that when i click a the current tab again the barImage resets. Now i just have to find a way to simulate a tabbar click on orientation change to make this work!

Comment: I'm assuming from the bounty you didn't find a way to simulate the tabbar click?

Comment: No haven't found a real good solution. see my answer for details what I've come up with. the bounty still stands for a better solution.

Comment: The only other thing I can possibly think of is to place a `landscape` width image forcibly `top: -40` behind the navbar so that when the smaller one is shown and the top right area is not covered the forced image would show but it's an ugly solution...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the "titleControl" on the Navbar to set the image instead of the barImage control?

also can you post a small apps.js file with the associated image somewhere? it is difficult to full grasp the problem without running the project

Comment: I've posted my app to the github: the app.js is found here: https://github.com/scubafly/Jobbroker-app/blob/master/Jobbroker/Resources/app.js

Comment: Also what do you mean with "titleControl" ?